# First cube theorem for homotopy cartesian squares?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, ct.category-theory, homotopy-theory

Does the following statement, similar to the first cube theorem (http://dx.doi.org/10.4153/CJM-1976-029-0) hold?:

-The left-hand and the rear face of a cube are homotopy cartesian (i. e. the left upper back corner of the cube is weakly equivalent to the homotopy pullbacks of this faces) and
-the bottom and the top faces are homotopy pushouts.

Then: The front and the right-hand faces are homotopy cartesian.

For me it would suffice to know this in the category of compactly generated weak Hausdorff spaces.

I hoped I could prove this, using the original first cube theorem, but I didn't manage to modifiy the cube (up to weak homotopy equivalence) such that the homotopy pullbacks of the left-hand face and the rear face coincide.

Comment: I don't understand how your statement differs from the first cube theorem.

Comment: @MikeShulman The difference is, that Mather asks the rear and left-hand face to be homotopy pullbacks (which are in his book unique up to homotopy equivalences). I only have a space at the left upper back corner, which is weakly homotopy equivalent to the homotopy pullbacks of these faces.

Comment: Oh, so you mean homotopy pullbacks in the Quillen model structure rather than the Hurewicz model structure?  In that case it should be an instance of descent for the $\infty$-topos of spaces, see e.g. https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/van+Kampen+colimit and section 6.1.3 of *Higher Topos Theory*.  In Rezk's *Toposes and homotopy toposes* he attributes the result for pushouts to Puppe https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~v1ranick/papers/puppe4.pdf.

Comment: Explicitly this can be found as HTT.6.1.3.14. The proof is as follows: model everything with simplicial sets, replace all the maps with minimal Kan fibrations, then observe that the claim becomes a fact about strict pushouts and pullbacks (which further reduces to the corresponding fact in the category of sets).